# assigning liquid to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

```
var first = 'one',
    second = 'two.png';
    image = first + second;
console.log('js image: ' + image);
image = '{{ image | asset_url }}';
console.log('liquid image: ' + image);
```

Produces in the console:

```
js image: onetwo.png
liquid image:
```

I cannot get the code to output the code from the liquid filter. I have tried using `{% raw %}` and looked at a few SO questions ([Shopify: Using variables from {% schema %} in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193655/shopify-using-variables-from-schema-in-javascript), [Using javascript variables in Shopify liquid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494309/using-javascript-variables-in-shopify-liquid), [Using asset_url within a .js.liquid file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258334/using-asset-url-within-a-js-liquid-file)) to no avail.

What am I doing wrong here? I am expecting to get:

```
liquid image: onetwo.png?123456789
```

Even removing `asset_url`:

```
image = '{{ image }}';
```

Still produces:

```
liquid image:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting with @Subhrajyoti Das there is a hacky way of doing it.

Create the full string with dummy text where the actual filename is:

```
assetString = '{{ 'filename' | asset_url }}'
```

This produces:

```
cdn.shopify.com/s/files/0/0000/0000/0000/t/00/assets/filename?0000000000
```

Then use string replacement to replace 'filename' with the asset variable:

```
image = assetString.replace("filename", image);
```

Comment: If this solved your query please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Rather than `var thing = '{{ some_liquid_variable }}'`, I always prefer using `var thing = {{ some_liquid_variable | json }}` - the `json` filter will always guarantee that the resulting output is javascript-legal, and will escape any weird characters, etc.  Not as important with a file name, but invaluable for anything like a description or the money format where quotation marks could appear.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the variable in the following way:

```
image = {{ 'image' | asset_url }};

//console log
js image: image.png
liquid image: image.png
```

Comment: This takes `image` as a string rather than referencing the variable, I will update my question to be clearer.

Comment: It will return you whatever is the value of `imagevar`. You can use it directly in src of the image tag.

Comment: It returns:
```liquid image: //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/0/0000/0000/0000/t/00/assets/image?0000000000```

Comment: how about if I wanted 'image' to be a variable?

Comment: If 'image' is a variable and can contain any value, and if the filename mentioned is present in the assets folder then it should work. I haven't tried it though. You can use the solution of the question if 'image' varies for you.